# Python Splitting String List and Adding Segment to Empty List

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have this code so far

```
data = ['fx_name_v002.1001.exr  fx_name_v002.1016.exr', 'fx_name_v002.1002.exr  fx_name_v002.1018.exr']
 data.sort()

frames = []

def string_split(data):
    for i in data:
        print(i.split('.'))
```

I need to split the list like I have. Once the list is split I need to add the 1002, 1001, of the split ends into the empty list frames.

The end result should be frames = ['1001', '1002', 'etc']

The part im confused on is the loop and after i split the list how to append the 1001, 1002, etc into the empty frames list.

Edit 1: Solved

Edit 2: So now I've been trying to reverse engineer regex and do research. How would I get the first part of the string, everything before 1001, 1002, etc. into a different list?

Comment: What about `1016` and `1018`?

Comment: Exactly which step are you stuck on?

Comment: im stuck on how to transfer the certain part of the split 1001, 1002, etc into the empty list frames

Comment: What exactly do you need to do ? What result are you supposing to get with the arguments you gave ? What are you trying to do and where is your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with regex!

```
import re

pattern = r'.(\d{4}).exr'
frames = re.findall(pattern, ' '.join(data))
print(frames)
# ['1001', '1016', '1002', '1018']
```

Comment: This works fine but only outputs 1001, i'd need to get 1002 and the rest

Comment: Really? Mine output all four of them in a list. Are you sure you're using `re.findall`?

Comment: Have you run either answer? You have put this exact comment on both answers, and this one runs fine for me

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, I had some conflicting code that messed with the output. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the numbers from the first file arg in each element

```
for i in data:
    var = i.split()[0]
    frames.append(var.split('.')[1])
```